# How to make front-matter page number non-bold in ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, chapters, bold, front-matter

Shown in the following pic:

[image]

It seems the Roman page number for front-matter look too dark in ToC, so how to make it as normal font but not change the bold Arabic number for chapters?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: I am using book class for dissertation writing. And the title of front matter is like: \chapter{Abstract} ... etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your global setting may differ slightly, but the following works:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book} 
\makeatletter
\def\@pnum@font{\bfseries}% Default is \bfseries
\renewcommand*\l@chapter[2]{% Taken from book.cls
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss\@pnum@font #2}\par
      \penalty\@highpenalty
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\g@addto@macro{\frontmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\def\protect\@pnum@font{\normalfont}}}
\g@addto@macro{\mainmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\def\protect\@pnum@font{\bfseries}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\frontmatter
\chapter{Acknowledgements}
\chapter{Abstract}
\chapter{List of Figures}
\chapter{List of Tables}
\chapter{Nomenclature}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Problem and motivation}
\section{Objectives}
\section{Research and methodology}
\subsection{Continuum}
%...
\end{document}
```

The macro responsibly for setting the `\chapter` titles in the ToC is `\l@chapter`. I've copied it from [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls) and inserted `\@pnum@font` where it sets the actual page number. By default, this has been defined to be `\bfseries` so that it prints in **bold**. Adding a `\normalfont` modification to `\frontmatter` and reversing it at `\mainmatter` (both using `\g@addto@macro`) causes a display that you're after.

Since writing to the ToC has to be done with care (to avoid expansion), using `\protect` is necessary.

Comment: The following is inspired by your code `\let\l@ochapter\l@chapter` `\def\l@nchapter#1#2{\l@ochapter{#1}{\mdseries #2}}` `\g@addto@macro{\frontmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}` `{\string\bgroup\let\string\l@chapter\string\l@nchapter}}` `\g@addto@macro{\mainmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\string\egroup}}`

Answer (score 0):

It nearly works in my case. See.
[image]

[XeLatex in Texlive 2012 Ubuntu]

The first front page number is bold and the chapter 1 number is normal.

I don't know why this happened, here is the tex code:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
 \include{Setting/settings}    % <----- page layout, font, renewcommands etc.

 \begin{document}
 \include{Cover/cover}     % cover page
 \frontmatter              % book mode only

 \pagenumbering{Roman}   
 \include{Acknowledgement/acknowledgement}
 \include{Abstract/abstract}

 {\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
 \tableofcontents }
 \listoffigures  
 \listoftables  
 \printnomenclature[1.6 cm]  
 \clearpage

 \mainmatter % book mode only
 \include{Introduction/introduction}
 \include{Chapter2/chapter2}
 \include{Chapter3/chapter3}
 \include{Chapter4/chapter4}
 \include{Conclusions/conclusions}

 ....
```

TOC content

```
\contentsline {chapter}{Acknowledgements}{i}{chapter*.1}
\def \@pnum@font {\normalfont }
\contentsline {chapter}{Abstract}{iii}{chapter*.2}
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Figures}{vii}{chapter*.4}
\contentsline {chapter}{List of Tables}{ix}{chapter*.5}
\contentsline {chapter}{Nomenclature}{xi}{chapter*.6}
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Introduction}{1}{chapter.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Problem and motivation}{1}{section.1.1}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Objectives}{3}{section.1.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.3}Research methodology}{4}{section.1.3}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.3.1}Continuum}{4}{subsection.1.3.1}
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.3.2}Discontinuum}{4}{subsection.1.3.2}
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.4}Thesis outline}{6}{section.1.4}
\def \@pnum@font {\bfseries }
\contentsline {chapter}{References}{9}{chapter*.7}
\contentsline {chapter}{Appendix A}{11}{appendix*.8}
\contentsline {chapter}{Appendix B}{13}{appendix*.9}
```

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}  is used to exclude 'Contents' in the list. Only Chapter 1 is included for test.

If I put \def \@pnum@font {\normalfont } on top and \def \@pnum@font {\bfseries } below Nomenclature in TOC, then recompile it, it works. But if run Bibtex, the orders will be of course disturbed again.

Comment: It's not likely to deduce what might be going on from just seeing an image of the output. Moreover, *this* does not constitute and answer to your question; it should rather be included as part of your original post. That's just how things work around here.

Comment: That's okay. But there is no way to add pic in comment?

Comment: Upload the image as part of an "answer" in order to get a link, and then post the link in the comment. It won't show, but clicking on it will reveal it. I'll check back tomorrow (off to bed now).

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. Have you compiled at least twice?

Comment: Here is the commands: xelatex thesis ----> bibtex thesis ----> xelatex thesis. Problem still persists.

Comment: Is `Setting/settings` a `.sty` or `.tex`? If its the former, use `\usepackage{Setting/settings}` or (if its the latter), use `\input{Setting/settings}`, but not `\include`. Is it in this file that you store the updates I suggested?

Comment: it's just a .tex file for preamble settings between \documentclass{book} and \begin{document}. \input{Setting/settings} seems not helping.

Comment: You could try `\makeatletter\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\def\protect\@pnum@font{\normalfont}}\makeatother` *directly* after `\frontmatter` and `\makeatletter\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\def\protect\@pnum@font{\bfseries}}\makeatother` *directly* after `\mainmatter` in the document itself (rather than including it in `Setting/settings`...

Comment: ...otherwise I am unable to replicate your problem. I suggest deleting all auxiliary files and recompiling. If the problem still persists, then you would have to reduce the problem into a manageable form by means of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv). Otherwise it is impossible to say what you might be doing differently that could cause the problem. In my examples, I'm able to produce the desired output *every* time, even after including [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: Thanks Werner. It did not work... Anyway, your code is useful, I could use it for the final work and change the TOC file manually.

Comment: I tried a simple Version of thesis tex. It works fine! Maybe I defined too many new commands in preamble and they might override by each other. But I could not figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Ideally you would remove things piece-by-piece while still being able to compile your document. This way you might be able to isolate where the problem occurs or what is causing it. Since this procedure is time-consuming and requires you to have a working document, it's best that you figure it out (I don't think you want to post your thesis here or elsewhere).